# C++, how to read CSV and remove comma

Tags: c++, csv

I would like to use C++ to read a .CSV file and extract each line and put each element separated by ',' into a 2D array. but there seems to be error in the reading and i cannot find the problem.

My C++ Code:

```
#include <fstream>  
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;  

int main( )  
{     
    std::string line2;  

    ifstream in2("sample-to-remove.txt");

    string entryLine[10][2];
    int x = 0;

    while (!in2.eof())
    {
        getline(in2, line2, '\n');
        stringstream ss(line2);

        std::string token;
        int y=0;
        while (std::getline(ss, token, ','))
        {
            std::cout << token << '\t';
            entryLine[x][y] = token;
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }

    for(int a= 0 ;  a < 10 ; a++ )
    {
        for(int b= 0 ;  b < 2 ; b++ )
        {
            cout << entryLine[a][b] << endl;
        }
    }

    in2.close();      

    return 0; 
}
```

My CSV File:

```
9834117,audriwxh@gmail.com
9234049,calinwj@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Related, have you [seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)?

Comment: `getline` then send to `stringstream` then pass via `getline(..., ',')`. Just take a look/research about it, and you'll figure out. Your code seems correct, so better post out an error, or why do you think it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors that I see:

1. The logic for getting out of the outer `while` loop is not right.

   After the you finish reading the first two lines, `in2.eof()` is still `fasle`. Hence, you continue to read a non-existent third line.

   Instead of

   ```
   while (!in2.eof())
   ```

   use

   ```
   while (getline(in2, line2, '\n'))
   ```
2. The printing loop prints too many lines.

   Instead of

   ```
   for(int a= 0 ;  a < 10 ; a++ )
   ```

   use

   ```
   for(int a= 0 ;  a < x ; a++ )
                  //  ^^^ You only have x lines not 10 lines.
   ```

Comment: Plus you know, he completely disregards quoted strings, which are used in normal CSV files.

Comment: @Blindy, you mean like `"a,b",c,d` where `"a,b"`is considered on entry in the file?